# PHP form validation - possible character set issue

Tags: php, regex, validation

Below is PART of a validation page.  Generally it works just fine. The site is low volume so wasnt too concerned with optimization for speed. My issue is that some users do not validate on valid data. Most users arent having any issues. As an example a customer entered in a street address of '2881 Hayden Creek Terrace' and the validation would not clear it. I am pretty new to this so it could be that these types of things are common but I am guessing the problem lies with the character set in the customers browser. Is this probably what I should look into? Does anybody see any major problems with the code in general?

```
function validation_payment($_check='') {

    $_error = '' ;

    foreach( $_POST as $key => $value ) {

    $value = preg_replace( "/[^\w@&#,\-\.\s\!\?]/",'',$value ) ;
    $value = preg_replace( "/\s\s+/"," ",$value ) ;
    //echo $value.'</br>' ;
    $_POST[$key] = $value ;

    switch ($key) {

        case 'ADDRESS_STREET_LINE1':
            $value = preg_replace("/[^\w,\-\.\s]/","",$value) ;
            if( empty($value) ) {
                $_error = "Error: Please make sure the Street Address entered on LINE 1 is not blank.<br/>" ;
            }elseif( !preg_match("/\s/",$value) ) {
                $_error .= "Error: The Street Address on LINE 1 does not appear to contain a street location and street name. Please review it for accuracy.<br/>" ;
            }elseif( !( strlen($value) < 100 ) ) {
                $_error .= 'Error: The Street Address entered on LINE 1 contains too many characters.<br/>' ;
            }else{
                $_SESSION['BILLING'][$key] = $value ;
            }
            break ;

}
```

Comment: Woah thats a bit too much code for me to go through right now. Do you know what parts of your code that fails? Could your narrow it down a bit?

Comment: ok removed most of the code.

Comment: Have you tried to get the input through your validation? What is the result? Error message?

Comment: No I was trying to avoid collecting the errors but I agree that is probably the best bet.

Comment: You know that there are very different formats for an address from country to country? IMO validating an address is a really bad idea. You can't even validate postal codes without knowing the country the customer comes from. Also what about including building and floor numbers for business addresses? An address "10-123 1/2 MAIN STREET NW, MONTREAL QC  H3Z 2Y7" is as valid as "Post Office Box 924, Ludhiana-141003".

Comment: @feela Very true but the pattern match here is pretty open. The only one I dont have is the '/' which I didnt even know existed. I will be sure to add it. This is just the validation for the first line of the address I just cut the rest out bc of how long the code was.

Comment: Going through your code, you should not be getting an error. `2881 Hayden Creek Terrace` will not match the regular expression you have provided (the replace stuff). Thus `empty()` wont be satisfied. The string contains a space which is a subset of whitespace matched with `\s`, so it won't fail there either. Lastly the string is 25 characters long. In the end, it should be placed into the session variable. You can clearly see the result of the replacements here: http://regex101.com/r/pF4xJ1

Comment: Thx Lindrian for verifying. The customer was swearing it was not working so I am at a loss. I enacted a few changes hoping to not run into the errors anymore and I have the errors being emailed to me, hopefully if anymore come up I can catch em. Thanks to everybody.